# How to compare two tables and find the difference between them in Linux using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I have to compare two MySQL database data, I want to compare two MySQL schema and find out the difference between both schema.

I have created two variables `Old_Release_DB` and `New_Release_DB`. In `Old_Release_DB` I have stored old release schema than after some modification like I deleted some column, added some column, renamed some column, changed column property like increase datatype size (ex: `varchar(10)` to `varchar(50)`). Then it became new release schema that I have stored in  `New_Release_DB`.

Now I want to Table Name, list of column name which has changed in `New_Release_DB`, and changes along with column name.

Example,

```
Table_A Column_Name Add(if it is added),
Table_A Column_Name Delete(if it is deleted),
Table_A Column_Name Change(if its property has changed)
```

I am trying it in shell script in Linux, but I am not getting it. Please let me know if I can use other script like Python or Java.

Comment: show show us what have you tried so far ? or at least ask clear question, it's unclear. show some data, file or etc.

Comment: I have two database one is "old-tables" and one is "new-tables". We have made some changes in "old-tables" database. then updated "old-tables" database we are calling it "new-tables" database.

Comment: Sounds like something that should be done in SQL, not shell scripting.

Comment: If you want to compare the descriptions (or some scripts), use e.g.  `diff(1)`

Answer (score 1):

To compare the differences between schemas of two mysql databases from the command line you can use [mysqldiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiff.html)

example usage from the documentation

```
shell> mysqldiff --server1=root@localhost \
          employees.salaries:emp1.salaries --differ

# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing employees.salaries to emp1.salaries                    [FAIL]
# Object definitions are not the same:
  CREATE TABLE `salaries` (
    `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `from_date` date NOT NULL,
    `to_date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`from_date`),
    KEY `emp_no` (`emp_no`)
- ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
?           ^^^^^
+ ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
?          ++ ^^^
Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

If the two datatabases are not the same the utility should return a non-zero exit code which you could incorporate into a shell script.
To me the long term solution to this problem is that this DB schema should really have its own [independent versioning system](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/).

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use Toad software which is a freeware and it has excellent options available to compare the databases, tables and schema.

Check here https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server

I found this very handy.